# SolrException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffffffff) was found

Tags: java, unicode, solr

I am passing a text file into Apache Solr and am getting the exception:

`SolrException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffffffff) was found`

I want to skip indexing the full content of this text file as a result.

How do I find if a text file has this character in Java?

To find Unicode 0xffff to fix a similar issue, I am currently using:

    `File file = [somefile];
    String contents = getContentsAsString(file);
    if (contents.contains("\uFFFF")) {
        [skip it] 
    }`

I need to determine if a text file contains Unicode: 0xffffffff.

Comment: This strikes me as very much the wrong solution - I suspect you're falling foul of another issue, such as the encoding not being set correctly... I'd double check things like that before using this sort of a "fix". (If you have to use this fix, then there's no way other than opening up the text file and iterating through each byte to check, similar to what you're doing already, though there's no need to hold the entire file contents in memory.)

Comment: How are you building the request to Solr?

Comment: There is no Unicode 0xffffffff character. It looks like at some point the code is expecting an integer corresponding to a Unicode codepoint, but gets -1 instead.

Comment: This is code in Eclipse Orion, the class is at http://git.eclipse.org/c/orion/org.eclipse.orion.server.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.orion.server.search/src/org/eclipse/orion/internal/server/search/Indexer.java

I think the key is that there is no Unicode 0xffffffff character so the current way we are doing things is wrong.

Comment: The problem file is from the zh_TW zone so is likely not UTF-8 and is some other encoding. How can I quickly tell if a file has non UTF-8 supported characters in it?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> There is no Unicode 0xffffffff character. It looks like at some point the code is expecting an integer corresponding to a Unicode codepoint, but gets -1 instead.
>
> This strikes me as very much the wrong solution - I suspect you're falling foul of another issue, such as the encoding not being set correctly... I'd double check things like that before using this sort of a "fix". (If you have to use this fix, then there's no way other than opening up the text file and iterating through each byte to check, similar to what you're doing already, though there's no need to hold the entire file contents in memory.)